# Django class based view mobile template

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm setting up Django to use a different template for mobile but I'm not sure how to set it up for Class based views. If I include it in the class like below it throws an error.

```
class EventList(ListView):
    model = Event
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'events'
    category = None
    area = None
    starts = None
    ends = None
    slug_level = ""
    if request.mobile:
        template_name = "mobile/mobile.html"

    ...
```

I have functions like `def get_queryset(self):` where to place it so it uses a different template for mobile since request isn't in the class based view

I'm using `minidetector` in function like so:

```
@detect_mobile
def home(request, template_name='pages/home.html'):
    ....
    if request.mobile:
        return render_to_response('mobile/mobile.html', context)
```

Comment: Have a look at [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile). Even if you decide not to use it, you will get the general idea to distinguish mobile vs non-mobile from its source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile and desktop will generally use the same HTTP methods, so CBV is not where you distnguish between these clients.

Instead, you should look at the client's properties such as the user-agent header and set the template name accordingly.

I think the following page gives a great intro:

http://mobiforge.com/design-development/build-a-mobile-and-desktop-friendly-application-django-15-minutes